# Sorting Algorithm For Array with Integers of at most n spots away

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an array with integers, with each integer being at most n positions away from its final position, what would be the best sorting algorithm?

I've been thinking for a while about this and I can't seem to get a good strategy to start dealing with this problem. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Do you need the best possible sorting algorithm, or just a good one? Many well-known sorts take advantage of "nearly sorted" lists (or can be tuned to do so), with performance approaching O(n), so if you don't need the best possible sort, just use one of those.

Comment: So something like insertion sort (which works well on almost sorted lists) would do it. What about the "best possible sort"? Or is that pretty hard to prove/obtain?

Comment: This is not very well defined as _all_ elements in _any_ list are at most n positions away from any other position. Russell is right, if there is something that makes your requirement of the sort unique this should be used to identify which algorithm will work best for the specific case...

Comment: @Killercam I'm guessing the question says that for example, assume a list of size 20, each item is at most 3 spots away from its final position. I would guess that as Russell explained, insertion sort would be most appropriate.

Comment: Given n=5 and A=[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], insertion sort is terrible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd split the list (of size N) into 2n sublists (using zero-based indexing):

list 0: elements 0, 2n, 4n, ... 
list 1: elements 1, 2n+1, 4n+1, ... 
... 
list 2n-1: elements 2n-1, 4n-1, ...

**Each of these lists is obviously sorted.**

Now merge these lists (repeatedly merging 2 lists at a time, or using a min heap with one element of each of these lists).

**That's all.** Time complexity is O(N log(n)).

This is easy in Python:

```
>>> a = [1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 8, 9, 7, 12, 13, 10, 11]
>>> n = max(abs(i - x) for i, x in enumerate(a))
>>> n
3
>>> print(*heapq.merge(*(a[i::2 * n] for i in range(2 * n))))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

Comment: Why would you do this splitting?

Comment: @Nayefc: To get sorted lists (without explicit sorting!).

Answer (score 1):

The [Heap Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/heap-sort) is very fast for initially random array/collection of elements. In pseudo code this sort would be imlemented as follows:

```
# heapify
for i = n/2:1, sink(a,i,n)
→ invariant: a[1,n] in heap order

# sortdown
for i = 1:n,
    swap a[1,n-i+1]
    sink(a,1,n-i)
    → invariant: a[n-i+1,n] in final position
end

# sink from i in a[1..n]
function sink(a,i,n):
    # {lc,rc,mc} = {left,right,max} child index
    lc = 2*i
    if lc > n, return # no children
    rc = lc + 1
    mc = (rc > n) ? lc : (a[lc] > a[rc]) ? lc : rc
    if a[i] >= a[mc], return # heap ordered
    swap a[i,mc]
    sink(a,mc,n)
```

For different cases like "Nearly Sorted" of "Few Unique" the algorithms can work differently and be more efficent. For a complete list of the algorithms with animations in the various cases see [this brilliant site](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/).

I hope this helps.

Ps. For nearly sorted sets (as commented above) the insertion sort is your winner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a [comb sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort), just start it with a gap size equal to the maximum distance away (or about there). It's expected O(n log n) (or in your case O(n log d) where d is the maximum displacement), easy to understand, easy to implement, and will work even when the elements are displaced more than you expect. If you need the guaranteed execution time you can use something like heap sort, but in the past I've found the overhead in space or computation time usually isn't worth it and end up implementing nearly anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Since `each integer being at most n positions away from its final position`:

1) for the smallest integer (aka. the 0th integer in the final sorted array), its current position must be in A[0...n] because the nth element is n positions away from the 0th position

2) for the second smallest integer (aka. the 1st integer in the final sorted array, zero based), its current position must be in A[0...n+1]

3) for the ith smallest integer, its current position must be in A[i-n...i+n]

We could use a (n+1)-size min heap, containing a rolling window to get the array sorted. And you could find more details here:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nearly-sorted-algorithm/